# Is variable sized 2D array declaration wrong？

Tags: c, sizeof

Here is main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int size = atoi(argv[1]);

    int int_array[10][10];

    int *before = NULL;
    int *val[size];
    int *after = NULL;
    printf("before:%p, after:%p, sizeof val:%lu\n", before, after, sizeof val);

    int i = 0;
    /*for (; i < 10; i++) {
        val[i] = int_array[i];
    }*/
    val[0] = int_array[0];
    val[1] = int_array[3];

    printf("int_array:%p, int_array[0]:%p, int_array[1]:%p, int_array[2]:%p, int_array[3]:%p\n", int_array, int_array[0], int_array[1], int_array[2], int_array[3]);
    printf("val:%p, val[0]:%p, val[1]:%p, val[2]:%p, val[3]:%p\n", val, val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3]);
    printf("before:%p, after:%p\n", before, after);

    return 0;
}
```

```
[root@localhost test]# ./test 3
before:(nil), after:(nil), sizeof val:24
int_array:0x7ffeadc69470, int_array[0]:0x7ffeadc69470, int_array[1]:0x7ffeadc69498, int_array[2]:0x7ffeadc694c0, int_array[3]:0x7ffeadc694e8
val:0x7ffeadc69440, val[0]:0x7ffeadc69470, val[1]:0x7ffeadc694e8, val[2]:0x3, val[3]:0x4005ba
before:(nil), after:(nil)

[root@localhost test]# ./test 6
before:(nil), after:(nil), sizeof val:48
int_array:0x7ffcd30f1f50, int_array[0]:0x7ffcd30f1f50, int_array[1]:0x7ffcd30f1f78, int_array[2]:0x7ffcd30f1fa0, int_array[3]:0x7ffcd30f1fc8
val:0x7ffcd30f1f00, val[0]:0x7ffcd30f1f50, val[1]:0x7ffcd30f1fc8, val[2]:0x7ffcd30f2220, val[3]:(nil)
before:(nil), after:(nil)
```

compile the code: gcc -o test main.c, then I got output above by ./test 3 and ./test 6.
so, it's not the compiling time but runtime when `sizeof()` is determined?

Comment: *"it's not the compiling time but runtime when sizeof() is determined?"* Normally it's at compile time, but for VLAs, it has to determine them at runtime. Note that VLAs aren't actually part of C++ and this only works on compilers that tolerate them nevertheless.

Comment: Since this is entirely C code (including the extension on the filename), it should be tagged C and not C++.

Comment: "Is variable sized 2D array declaration wrong？" ---> there is no variable sized 2D array in the code.

Answer (score 8):

> Is variable sized 2D array declaration wrong？

In C++, the size of all array variables must be a compile time constant. `size` is not a compile time constant, and therefore `int *val[size];` is ill-formed in C++.

Answer (score 0):

For VLAs, yes, the result of `sizeof` is computed at runtime:

> **6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators**
> ...
> 2 The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
> expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
> the operand. The result is an integer. *If the type of the operand is a variable length array
> type, the operand is evaluated;* otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
> integer constant.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Emphasis added.

This makes sense, since the size of a VLA isn't established until runtime.

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish with `before` and `after` - if you're trying to see what addresses `val` takes up, this isn't the way to do it.  First of all, you'd want to print the values of `&before` and `&after`, but even so there's no guarantee that objects are laid out in memory in the same order that they were declared.  It's also not guaranteed that VLAs are allocated from the same region of memory as other `auto` variables (they usually are, but it's not required).

Answer (score 0):

Thank John and Blaze, and yes, it's `VALs`(variable array length), which is supported by GNU C compiler(gcc) as a extension since C99. So lots of things depend on compiler.

Here is more to learn, found in Wikipedia:
Allocation

- The GNU C Compiler allocates memory for VLAs with automatic storage
  duration on the stack.[4] VLAs, like all objects in C, are limited to
  SIZE_MAX bytes.[5]
- VLAs can also be allocated on the heap and accessed using a pointer to VLA.